# Why doesn't the code below produce any output?

Tags: python

There are two code snippets, the upper one works but the lower one does not. Why doesn't second code snippet output anything?

```
#This code works:
x=["Decomplete asd"]
y=[]
z=[]
for i in x:
    if "De" in i:
        y.append(i)
        print(y)
    if "comp" in i:
        z.append(i)
        print(z)

# This one does not:
x=["Decomplete asd"]
y=[]
z=[]
if "De" in x:
    y.append(x)
    print(y)
if "comp" in x:
    z.append(x)
    print(z)
```

Comment: There are many Python debuggers and linters out there. Some are even already on your computer. What steps have you taken to solve this yourself? Also, what do you mean by code "working" or "not working"? [Edit] the question and tell us what you have tried and what you expect.

Comment: Try to be more specific indeed. What do you mean by 'not working'? Not the expected output? Then please post what you *do* expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome Nicathus !

That's because x is a **list** that contains one string. But x is not a string itself.

So :

- in the first case, i takes the value of each **item** in this list (as this list's length = 1 , the loop will be quickly done). So when i is the item "Decomplete asd", which is a **string**, the conditions are true : "De" and "comp" are in this string.
- in the second case, the conditions apply directly to x. And x is a list, not a string. It means that you're looking for the strings "De" and "comp" in a list that does not contain them, as items.

It would work if you had `x = ["De", "comp", "hello"]` for instance.

Or if you had `x = "Decomplete asd"` (i.e. a string, without `[` and `]`).

Hope it helped !

Comment: Wow thanks alot , that was great explanation. I got it.  Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The code below the for loop checks for the **de**sired only once.

The code adds each string on every instance. Basically, the top code doesn't stop looking until the code goes through every part of the collection.